# A solution for `Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0`

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, string, web

This is one of the common errors I face offten. I was wondering if there is a solution to this.

```
let a = (str) => {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

`a()` parses the string to JSON and returns. What if we are never sure that the string passed to `a()` is always a JSON parsable string.

Ex: `a("hello world");`

this will result in

```
Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
```

Is there a smart way to parse the string to JSON? (By this i mean, is there a way to return the string in case if the string is not parsbale.)

Comment: That is a bad idea.  If something that is not supposed to be JSON happens to look like JSON, your code will break horribly (probably in ways that involve security holes).   You should fix your input.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. In some cases like where I request an API and print the body, if the body is expected to be a JSON but due to an error it is not. For example, it returned "not a valid token" where I expected a JSON. I think in this case, it is better to have `isJSON()` function like Marcos said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is not a `JSON`, and you wish to return that string, just `return` it.

```
let a = (str) => {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        // Instead of error, return str
        return str;
    }
}
```

`JSON.parse` will throw for non `JSON` strings. Most `JSON` validators do the following:

```
function isJSON(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So your code is perfectly valid, you just need to return the string on error, if you expect non `JSON` strings.

Anyhow, if your function expects a JSON, and you receive a non JSON string, you should probably not return the same string. I would return a falsey value or just let the error bubble up.

Comment: is it good practice to have a function returning different types ? like, some times it returns a `json object` , other times a `string` ?

Comment: I usually return one type or `null` / `false` on some error, but I don't think it's bad practice, given that it is documented correctly.

Comment: Taki, actually it depends. If the function is used just to print the data, we still want the data to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

As Marcos says if you want to simply return the String, then in your catch return the input param.

However if you want to ensure, what is returned is always of a consistent data type i.e. always return a `Map/JSON` instead of sometimes returning a `String`

You can convert your string into a Key-Value map object using something like this:

```
let a = (str) => {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        // Instead of error, return str as json object
        return {"value": str};
    }
}
```

You can then access the String as `a.value`